# Why does maven cause an error when I try to clean my Project?

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am using STS, Spring 3.1 RC, and Maven. I am following this tutorial: http://manueljordan.wordpress.com/2011/12/12/creating-a-spring-web-mvc-project-with-springsource-tool-suite/ 
 
I am attempting to clean my project as in the tutorial, after modifying the Spring version and adding a repository. I get this error:

```
    Errors occurred during the build.
    Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'PracticeApp'.
    Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\Joe\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\Joe\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    Could not calculate build plan: Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\Joe\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    Failed to parse plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.1.1 (C:\Users\Joe\.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-war-plugin\2.1.1\maven-war-plugin-2.1.1.jar): invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

What is it that is going wrong here? I have attempted to restart the tutorial and followed it carefully and nothing has changed. I would appreciate a little bit of help here.
Thanks.

Comment: Also attach your pom information for war plugin.

Comment: I did indeed add information to the question. The above snippet contains the full error message.

Comment: The error states war plugin jar is corrupted. Manually delete and try again.

Comment: That worked. Now just have to figure out the new error it creates on init. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pom file seems to be corrupted(missing tag, spell check, etc). Your error snippet mentions the war plugin is misconfigured. Try to fix that. It is easier if you are using eclipse or some ide with maven plugin which can tell you what portion of pom is incorrect and sometimes suggest correct solution too.

Comment: STS is a remake of Eclipse with a Maven plugin.